# session state of checkbox list

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can you please help me in storing the checkbox list items in session.

I have a checkbox list as follows

```
asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblScope" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="cblScope_SelectedIndexChanged">

    asp:ListItem ID="liInScope" runat="server" Value="true">In Scope (Monitored)</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem ID="liOutOfScope" runat="server" Value="true">Out of Scope (Unmonitored)</asp:ListItem>

/asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I have to store the value of the checkbox in session when they are cheked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add ALL the items (whether checked or not) to session like this:

```
Session.Add("AllItems", cblScope.Items);
```

Or you can just add the checked ones with a bit more code:

```
List<ListItem> selectItems = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (ListItem item in cblScope.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
        selectItems.Add(item);
}

Session.Add("MySelectedItems", selectItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

ID and runat are not appropriate tags for ListItems. Your checkboxlist should look more like this

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblScope" runat="server"  
        onselectedindexchanged="cblScope_SelectedIndexChanged"> 

    <asp:ListItem Value="In Scope">In Scope (Monitored)</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem Value="Out of Scope">Out of Scope (Unmonitored)</asp:ListItem> 

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Note that in a checkboxlist, many items can be selected. If you are intending this to be a single selection, you should use a RadioButtonList control instead. As for getting the items that have been selected, you can iterate over them or even use LINQ. Here are examples storing the selected values in a list of strings.

Iteration:

```
List<string> selections = new List<string>();
foreach (ListItem listItem in cblScope.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected)
    {
        selections.Add(listItem.Value);                
    }
}

Session["selections"] = selections;
```

LINQ:

```
var selections = (from ListItem listItem in cblScope.Items
                  where listItem.Selected
                  select listItem.Value).ToList();

Session["selections"] = selections;
```

Answer (score 2):

Page A:

```
//Add namespace for List

using System.Collection.Generic;

protected void BtnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                

        List<ListItem> selection = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (ListItem li in CheckBoxList1.Items)
        {
            if (li.Selected)
            {
                selection.Add(li);
                //string ch = li.Value;
            } 
        }
        Session["emp"] = selection;
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
        //Server.Transfer("Page2.aspx");

    }
```

Page 2:-

```
using System.Collection.Generic;

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["emp"] != null)
        {
            List<ListItem> name=(List<ListItem>)Session["emp"];           

            foreach (ListItem li in name)
            {
               Response.Write(li);
            }
        }
     }
```